# What's the meaning of "gas" here?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

> Todays Alpha males are MMA/Jits fighters not meatheads who gas 15-30 seconds after raising their heart rate. This aint the 80/90s bro.

Is this some kind of thing bodybuilders inhale? How does it work?

Comment: Could be a thing, or could be a typo for 'gasp' (i.e. 'Todays Alpha males' are much better than 'meatheads').

Comment: If it's a thing, maybe it's [oxygen supplementation during exercise](http://www.pponline.co.uk/encyc/ergogenic-aids-can-increasing-oxygen-levels-improve-sports-performance-95).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the author is talking about losing their energy after a short period of time

Comment: This answer can be improved by citing a reputable source.

Answer (score 7):

The sentence is saying that today's MMA/Jits fighters are much more physically fit and trained than "meatheads" of the past, and thus don't "gas out," or "run out of gas [energy]" as quickly. "Gas" comes from shortening "[run out of gas](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/gassing)."

It is common in martial arts, mixed martial arts, MMA, etc. to say something like:

"I gassed out too quickly; I must not have trained hard enough."

"If you are gassing during [insert event], then you may need to [insert advice]."

You could use "becoming fatigued," "running out of/running low on energy," and "running out of steam" in the same way.

Comment: It isn't just common in MMA. I hear the term a lot in reference to soccer players who are tired and need a substitution.

Comment: Do you have any examples of someone shortening "run out of gas" to "gas"? I'm not familiar with the shortened usage. Couldn't it just as easily mean "step on the gas"? Maybe it's idiomatic in sports circles?

Comment: @Zairja - No, it does *not* mean "step on the gas". Yes, it is mostly likely idiomatic in sports circles, but that doesn't mean much considering our culture's fondness for sports metaphors.

Comment: The original uses 'gas' not 'gas out'. Do you have any support that these are synonymous ('gas' by itself does not 'feel' like 'to run out of gas'. Do you have any real instances of 'gas' by itself (without the 'out')?

Comment: @Mitch and Zairja: I agree with you that *gas* by itself, logically, could go either way. But slang is not subject to logic. (Maybe I should say slang is even *less* subject to logic than "standard" English.)

Comment: @ Mitch: In answer to your question, posts on the Team Takeover forums should frequent use of "gas" in place of "fatigue" or "tired." For an example, see this post: [Do MMA fighters gas because they are lazy?](http://teamtakeover.forum-express.com/t9414-do-mma-fighters-gas-because-they-re-lazy).

Without "out," "gas" is being used more like "become tired" rather than a noun replacement for "energy."

Here you'll see all forms together and used the same way: [Myths of MMA Conditioning](http://www.8weeksout.com/2011/11/02/myths-of-mma-conditioning/).

Comment: Nice. Those examples are convincing.

Answer (score 0):

"gas" is actually not JUST becoming fatigued, though that is the result. It involves the physiology of gas exchange at the cellular level, with oxygen being required by the muscles, but only enough being provided by the body to supply minimal function.
When someone is gassed in mma, they literally cannot recover with a few deep breaths and a sit between rounds. It's a metabolic state, and they are likely to lose that fight.